# jQuery sortable bug when dragging more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

There's a bug I can't get rid of using sortable() on multiple lists. I'm able to drag more than one item by adding the following to the start function:

```
  e.item.siblings(".selected").appendTo(e.item);
```

But now when you're not over top of a drop zone the placeholder comes with the items I drag. I can visually see the placeholder inside the dragged elements. And if I drop it at this point, they disappear. I tried to fix it using:

```
 e.item.siblings(".selected").not('.placeholder').appendTo(e.item);
```

In this fiddle the issue is very apparent.

http://jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/kxBUG/

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQueryUI extension that does what you need I think.

You can search there for some answers. It can be found [here](https://github.com/iamvery/jquery.multisortable)